# check if a file exist using parts of the file name in R

Tags: r

Lets say my file name is `"fileparts1.txt"`
I would like to check if the file with above name exist in a folder based on some parts of the file name character?

For example:

```
file.exist(filepar*)
```

How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead (as a logical test):

```
 length( list.files( path = foldername, patt= "filepar") ) > 0
```

Comment: This is probably preferable to `grepl` as it only returns a subset of the file list.

Answer (score 2):

Using `grepl` maybe?:

```
any(grepl("test",list.files()))
#[1] TRUE
```